# Api call using CURL in Android

Tags: android, curl, post

I have an API, and I have to use cURL to communicate.
The cURL command is:

```
cURL -k -d "key=some_value" -d "key2=someValue2" https://www.myUrl
```

I have no idea how to proceed.I searched a lot but not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
curl 'http://<Your Address>/<Web Service End Address>?<Variable1=value1&Varuable2=value2'
```